# Writing to String and Binary Files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Not too many have answered my questions at all.  What I want to do a to use private copy constructors and assign them to variables as string or binary files.

Here is the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class President
{
private:
President() {};
President(const President&);
const President& operator=(const President&);
string Name;

public:
static President& GetInstance()
{
    static President OnlyInstance;
    return OnlyInstance;
}

string GetFile()
{

    cout<<"Enter the name of the file you want to protect: ";
    cin>>Name;
    ofstream fsOut;
    fsOut.open(Name, ios_base::out, ios_base::binary);
    if(fsOut.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"Writing to binary file."<<endl;
        fsOut<<Name<<endl;
        cout<<"File open successful."<<endl;

    fsOut.close();
    }
    return Name;
}

void SetFile(string InputFile)
{
    Name=InputFile;
}

};


int main()
{
string Name;
President& OnlyPresident=President::GetInstance();
OnlyPresident.SetFile(Name);
cout<<President::GetInstance().GetFile()<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I have compiled it and it was fine. However, it was not running correctly or it did not correspond to the file, in which I have typed.  How could I protect files correctly using private copy constructors?

John P.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by protecting the file using private copy constructors. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `fsOut.open(Name, ios_base::out, ios_base::binary);` should not compile. What is your runtime issue exactly ?

Comment: `fsOut.open(Name, ios_base::out, ios_base::binary);` probably should be `fsOut.open(Name, ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);` You have to combine the flags with a bitwise OR.

Comment: Or you should not use `ios_base::out` since it is implied by using `ofstream`. Also, use `ios`, not `ios_base`. `fsOut.open(Name, ios::binary);

Comment: You have implemented a typical singleton pattern. For this pattern the copy-constructor is made private, which simply means that it is should not be implemented. I don't know what you mean by private copy-constructor for protecting files.